# Hide the addressbar/location of Html page

Tags: html

My code:

```
"HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(Uri), "_newWindow",
  "directories=no,fullscreen=no,menubar=no,location=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=no,titlebar=yes,toolbar=no,Width = 800");"
```

is not hiding the addressbar of the Html Page.

What is alternative code can I use to hide the addressbar?

Comment: what browser did you test it in?

Comment: Is your goal to hide *the location* of a page? If so, forget it. Just... forget it. Or do you just want to hide the address bar for esthetic reasons?

Comment: Tried both in IE9 nad Chrome

Comment: I want to hide the addressbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not address bar of html page. It's address bar element of browser UI. You shall not try to manipulate outside of your domain, which is just HTML page. For security reasons browsers shall not let you hide location bar

Comment: The actual scenario is on clicking a button in a silverlight page, a new html page will open. But the address bar of that html page will not be visible to the user.

Comment: As I said - forget it. You hopefuly will not be able to do that.